# pd.merge gives error: DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe, dfCM, which was created from another dataframe, dfdict[dfCM] and then processed as follows:

1. not needed rows were removed.
2. not needed columns were removed
3. new columns were added.

I now need to add back the deleted columns from dfdict[dfCM] to dfCM. Note that dfdict[dfCM] is saved within a dictionary of dataframes.

I've run a similar merge command multiple times in my code before, but now I'm getting the error: **DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**

```
#add back deleted dfCM columns 
dfCM = pd.merge(dfCM, dfdict[dfCM], on=['ClaimID'], how = 'left', suffixes = ('', '_cm')) 
#remove duplicate columns
dfCM.filter(like='_cm',axis=1)
```

This is what dfCM looks like (with many more cols and rows):

```
index ClaimID                 MeasCode  MeasAppType
0     MCE-2019-02-02-068-01     CLA48   AR  
1     MCE-2019-02-066-01        CLA48   AR  
2     MCE-2019-02-066-01B       CLA48   AR  
3     MCE-2019-02-066-02        CLB50   AR  
4     MCE-2019-02-066-02B       CLB50   AR  
5     MCE-2019-02-067-01        CLB51   AR
```

A screenshot of dfdict below:

[image: This is what dfdict looks like]

And this is what dfdict[dfCM] looks like (with many more rows and cols):

```
index   ClaimID                 MeasAppType  MeasDesc
0       BAY-2019_C&S_19Q1       AR           Attic insulation; Domestic hot water heater/boiler; 
1       BAY-2019_COM_19Q1       AR           Attic insulation; Domestic hot water heater/boiler; 
2       BAY-2019_Com_Q2         NR           This record is not a project
3       BAY-2019_CS_Q2          NR           This record is not a project
4       BAY-2019_EM&V_19Q1      AR           Attic insulation; Domestic hot water heater/boiler;
```

I was able to do the merge by changing all column names in dfdict[dfCM] as shown below. But this is not ideal as now I cannot differentiate between duplicate columns and unique columns added to dfCM and hence cannot delete the duplicates.

```
    #add back deleted dfCM columns
    dfdict['dfCM'] = dfdict['dfCM'].add_suffix('_cm') #identified columns from dfCL
    dfCM = pd.merge(dfCM, dfdict['dfCM'], left_on='ClaimID', right_on='ClaimID_cm', how = 'left', suffixes = ('', '_cm'))
```

Is there's a better way to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is `dfdict` a dictionary? If so, and `dfCM` is a dataframe, then you can't use it as a dictionary key because it is mutable as the error tells you

Comment: I tried creating a new df, a = dfdict[dfCM] and then used a instead of dfdict[dfCM], but got the same error. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Does `a = dfdict[dfCM]` give you that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to explain how you create `dfdict` as you are trying to use a dataframe as a key to a dictionary which you can't do:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
dfdict = {df1: 1, df2: 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgolding/PycharmProjects/team-general-wikis/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-3207e8fd0e73>", line 1, in <module>
    {df1: 1, df2: 2}
  File "/Users/dgolding/PycharmProjects/team-general-wikis/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1887, in __hash__
    " hashed".format(self.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

perhaps your dictionary keys are actually strings of the dataframe variable names? In this case you'd get that error when you tried to use the dataframe as a key to get a value:

```
dfdict = {"df1": df1, "df2": df2}
dfdict[df1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgolding/PycharmProjects/team-general-wikis/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-825e4ae2577b>", line 1, in <module>
    dfdict[df1]
  File "/Users/dgolding/PycharmProjects/team-general-wikis/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1887, in __hash__
    " hashed".format(self.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Maybe you were trying to do this: `dfdict["dfCM"]`?

Comment: Gosh! yes I was missing the quotes! What a silly error! Thanks for your help Dan.